# Rails 4 - thinking-sphinx date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a model object which have a start and end date. When searching I would like to add a condition where I only get objects that have a `start_date` that is before `Time.now`and an `end_date` the is after `Time.now`, that is objects that are `ongoing`.

I have tried the following:

```
@team = Team.find_by_id(params[:team_id])

# start_date and end_date are properties on my model object, that I want to filter based on.
@competitions = @team.competitions.search(params[:search], conditions: { :start_date => start_date..Time.now.to_i, :end_date => end_date..Time.now.to_i }, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :order => 'created_at DESC')
```

This results in the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `start_date'
```

Any ideas on what I should do to get my wanted behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will do the trick:

```
@competitions = @team.competitions.search params[:search],
  :select   => '*, start_date < NOW() AND end_date > NOW() as current',
  :with     => {:current => true},
  :page     => params[:page],
  :per_page => 10,
  :order    => 'created_at DESC'
```

This generates a custom attribute on the fly (`current`) and then filters by that.